# Blank screen after deploying React Vite project on Netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, vite, netlify

I have had no problems locally running my project. After deploying on Netlify, I get blank screen and on console saying "(Loading module from https://mywebsite.netlify.app/src/main.jsx was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (application/octet-stream)."

I have no clue how to solve this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

I have tried to include _headers file, but it did not help.